# AfterburnerFX load error File xyz.fxml not found, attempting with camel case

Tags: java, dependency-injection

After moving my project to Java 11 (from 10) afterburner fx is kicking up this load error

[image]

Now I've seen similiar questions which imply the source of this error tends to be from not following the proper naming convention, which I'm sure I am because my project used to start fine:

[image]

Can anyone think of what might be wrong? Really at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late. But hope it will help someone...

Afterburner requires [javax.annotation](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/javax.annotation-api) for JDK 11. I've added this in my pom.xml. And the app runs.